# Integral operator doesn't attain its norm

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $L:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be the bounded linear operator
$$
L(f)(t) = \int_0^1 f(t+s) ds = \int_t^{t+1} f(s) ds
$$
I have already shown that $\lVert L \rVert = 1$, and now I would like to show that this operator does not attain its norm i.e. $\lVert L(f) \rVert_2 = \lVert f \rVert_2$ iff $f=0$ a.e. but I don't really see where to start. Is there a nice way to see this?

Comment: Did you try transforming to the Fourier domain?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: The RHS is a convolution, so in the Fourier domain it is a multiplication.

Comment: I think the operator of multiplication by a function $g$ does not attain its norm if $g$ attains its (absolute) maximum only at a point.